# Communicating with objective-C from JS in phonegap?

Tags: javascript, ios, file, cordova, icloud

I need to get the iCloud directory, so I'd like to have some iOS bridge to get the directory name.

```
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]
                   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    if (ubiq) {
        NSLog(@"iCloud access at %@", ubiq);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"No iCloud access");
    }
```

This gives me the url, but I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
window.ios.getICloudDirectory(function(directory){
//do stuff with the iCloud directory
});
```

What is the easiest and least-code method of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Create a plugin.](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_plugin-development_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide) This is the fastest way to go.