# Send data from JS to parent with PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am experimenting with PhoneGap on Android and am embedding the `CordovaWebView` in an `Activity` that implements the `CordovaInterface`. I want to know if it is possible to send some data from JavaScript to the parent that contains the `CordovaWebView`.

In the CordovaInterface there is a method onMessage and I assumed that it would be possible to handle messages from JS there, but I can't seem to find documentation on how that works.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12764705/communicating-with-objective-c-from-js-in-phonegap) I saw that creating a plugin would do it, but is that the only way? Isn't there something that is already implemented in PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may or may not help you but if you want to see an example of how a plugin is implemented I've done this on [my blog](http://thewahlstedts.blogspot.com/2012/12/upgrading-phonegap-plugin-for-saving.html). It does allow you to communicate between the two and is probably your best bet in doing so. My understanding is this is the reasoning for the plugin interface in PhoneGap.

Comment: thanks, but I already implemented it myself. Will take a look though.